# MongoDB: query on average with $expr operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to query documents based on the computed average of two values.

e.g.

```js
db.test.insert([
  { "_id": 1, "category": "food", "budget": 400, "spent": 450 },
  { "_id": 2, "category": "drinks", "budget": 100, "spent": 150 },
  { "_id": 3, "category": "clothes", "budget": 100, "spent": 50 },
])
```

For example, how do I get the documents which average between budget and spent is greater than 100?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `$avg` and `$gt`:

```js
db.test.find( { $expr: { $gt: [{$avg: [ "$spent", "$budget" ] }, 100] } } )
{ "_id" : 1, "category" : "food", "budget" : 400, "spent" : 450 }
{ "_id" : 2, "category" : "drinks", "budget" : 100, "spent" : 150 }
```